# Possible to exclude subfolder from https rewrite?

Tags: http, redirect, https, iis-8

I have a webiste that runs https. Now some programmers need a subfoder that has no https.

This is what i have in my web.config right now:

```
<rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

We need the folder "wp-content\rest" to be excluded from this https redirect.

In hope someone can help me with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional condition into your rule:

```
<rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/wp-content/rest" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Then this rule will disable redirects to all urls like that `http://www.example.com/wp-content/rest*`